# Microsoft Visual basic 6.5 Ignore case

Tags: vba, excel

I am using microsoft visual basic 6.5 and Excel

`TxtMMM` is a `String prompt keyyed in by user. In this case i hardcoded it as an example
but it(`TxtMMM) could be any of "Jan", "JAN", "jAn" or "jan" etc

My problem would be, how can i write to the condition to check the `TxtMMM`, to **ignore case sensitive** while checking?

E.g if the user input `TxtMMM`

- JAN
- jan
- JaN

then it will should return `"01"`

```
sub casesense()    
Dim TxtMMM as String    
Dim sTxtMMM as String    
TxtMMM = "Jan"    
            If TxtMMM = "JAN" Then
                sTxtMMM = "01"
                csd = 1
            ElseIf TxtMMM = "FEB" Then
                sTxtMMM = "02"
                csd = 1
                .....
             End If
End sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than a 12 step `Select` why not

```
Dim TxtMMM As String
TxtMMM = "Jan"
MsgBox Format(Month(DateValue("1/" & TxtMMM & "/2013")), "00")
csd = 1
```

Comment: Why not close the loop by having `csd = month(...`?

Comment: As in the example given both `Jan` and `Feb` had `csd=1`.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. Just use UCase to convert TxtMM to uppercase first, and then compare:

```
    If UCase(TxtMMM) = "JAN" Then
        sTxtMMM = "01"
        csd = 1
    ElseIf UCase(TxtMMM) = "FEB" Then
        sTxtMMM = "02"
        csd = 1
        .....
     End If
```

Comment: by doing that, will it change it value of TxtMMM? or only affect for that statement only?

Comment: It won't change value of TxtMMM. Effect will be for that statement (If condition) only.